# How can I change color of background or text of function parameter hint in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I try to change a color of background or text ( better - text ). But dont know where to do that...

[in red is the thing that i need to change] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yHS8.png)

Tryed Settings -> Color Schema -> General -> Popups and Hints... But it doesnt work :(